# How do I set a background image using Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to set a background image in the first `UIViewController`. I'm dragging the `UIImageView` from the *Object library* and placing it on the `UIViewController`. Afterwords, I select the the background image but other objects get selected because they overlap the image. Is there any way to select the background image and not the other objects?

Comment: Can you show a picture so it's clear what you mean with overlap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your storyboard, and find this button at the bottom left corner:

[image]

You should see this on your left now:

[image]

Now drag your image view object under any other object you wish on the left hand side under your view controller scene. An example would be that if you had this persons objects in your view controller you would put the image view before the button.

Hope this helped.